# How to compare visually two look alike videos of different codec, size, resolution

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing

Is it possible to compare pragmatically, two look alike videos of different codec, size and resolution. I went through the some tools like `ffmpeg` `opencv`.

Or in the another context, Lets an image should be compared with video and find out the exact time where the image visually present in the given video. The codecs, size and resolution of video and image may vary.

Comment: Open them in VLC media player,  tools -> codec information

Comment: Do you mean compare the codec information, or compare the actual visual information? What do you mean by compare? brightness/FPS/people in the scene. You really need to explain your question a lot more

Comment: @GPPK compare the visual information not codec, as I mentioned earlier the videos  would be different codecs. Lets say I have an image and an video. I need to find the image in video given, both are different codecs and resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research and going through the forums, I got [OpenSIFT](https://robwhess.github.io/opensift/) library(depends on [opencv](http://opencv.org/)). In this, **match** algorithm satisfies with the task.In this algorithm **any two images of different size,codec can be compared.**
For video comparison, convert the video into frames and compared each frame with reference image.

I hope this will be helpful if anybody searching for a image/frame in the video **visually** rather than raw frames comparison

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it involves work. So, I'm assuming here you'll use ffmpeg (libavformat, libavcodec) programmatically, you can probably do the same through intermediate layers such as opencv also.

First, open the videos (using [libavformat](https://ffmpeg.org/libavformat.html)), decode the frame(s) (using [libavcodec](https://ffmpeg.org/libavcodec.html)), and rescale them (using [libswscale](https://ffmpeg.org/libswscale.html)) so they're of identical size and picture format (e.g. yuv420p). Which of the two videos/images you rescale shouldn't matter, but if you're comparing an image to a video, I'd scale the image since that's a single instead of per-frame operation. Then, compare that image to each output frame (using the [ssim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ssim) of [psnr](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#psnr) filters in [libavfilter](https://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html)), and check the metadata of the output frame for lavfi.ssim.dB or lavfi.psnr.psnr_avg. The frame that the image is most similar to is the frame with the highest PSNR or SSIM score, which is the answer to your question.

You will find tutorials and examples for each of these libraries if you choose to use them.